# Categorizing GHC extensions

Tags: compiler-construction, haskell, ghc, type-systems

I was wondering if GHC's extensions can be divided into basically two different categories

- those that provide "syntactic suggar" or convenience
- and those that introduce something new, a new paradigm for instance.

Now provided one could divide the existing extensions into the above categories which extension would fit into which category?

Comment: I'm not sure how meaningful that distinction is--given Turing completeness, in some sense everything else is just "convenience". Granted, writing Haskell instead of, oh, Lazy K is **extremely** convenient indeed...

Answer (score 8):

I think a more appropriate categorization would be to divide it up by the compiler pipeline:

**Syntactic extensions**

- -XMagicHash
- -XUnicodeSyntax
- -XNewQualifiedOperators
- -XViewPatterns
- -XNPlusKPatterns
- -XDoRec
- -XTransformListComp
- -XNoImplicitPrelude
- -XPostfixOperators
- -XTupleSections
- -XDisambiguateRecordFields
- -XNamedFieldPuns
- -XRecordWildCards
- -XPackageImports
- -XExplicitForAll
- -XKindSignatures
- ...

**Type System Extensions**

- -XUnboxedTuples
- -XLiberalTypeSynonyms
- -XGADTs
- -XMultiParamTypeClasses
- -XFlexibleContexts
- -XConstrainedClassMethods
- -XOverlappingInstances and -XIncoherentInstances
- -XTypeFamilies
- -XImplicitParams

**Cross-cutting extensions**

- -XTemplateHaskell
- -XForeignFunctionInterface

**Optimizatsions**

- -fenable-rewrite-rules
- -fspec-constr
- -O2

**Code Generation Extensions**

- -fllvm
- -fasm
- -fvia-C

**Runtime Extensions**

- -threaded

What do you think? Not every flag is either (a) definable in terms of existing constructions, or (b) a new part of the compiler. It's more subtle.

There are many other extensions too, see if you can classify them in this form.

Comment: Why "Cross-Cutting" as a label for FFI and TH?

Comment: @Jason Dusek: Because they have a far-reaching impact on multiple aspects of the language, I imagine--either invoking arbitrary external code or making arbitrary changes to the code at compile time.

Comment: Oh, because they modify all aspects of the compiler and runtime: syntax, types, code generation and runtime support.

Answer (score 2):

The flags are already categorized in the [flag reference](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html) in the GHC's users guide, and the language extensions are broken down into various categories in the section on [language features](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/ghc-language-features.html#options-language).